# MySQL: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I cant find explanation of MySQL behavior. Examples are below.

Fields `name` and `name_full` are `text` type and field `price_steps` is `json` type. None of them has index.

```
SELECT
    name,
    name_full,
    price_steps
FROM
    `lots`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `categories`
        INNER JOIN `category_lot` ON `categories`.`id` = `category_lot`.`category_id`
        WHERE
            `lots`.`id` = `category_lot`.`lot_id`
        AND `category_id` IN (25)
    )
ORDER BY
    `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 31 OFFSET 0
```

MySQL throws error: [Err] 1038 - Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size.

Ok, let it be.

Then I added extra field into select part.

```
SUBSTRING(`name_full`, 1, 200000000000) as name_full2
```

and query runs successfully *(Why? Extra field should lead to extra memory allocation, isnt it?)*.

Then I decided to make query heavier and replace string

```
AND `category_id` IN (25)
```

with

```
AND `category_id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 25)
```

and the query also finishes successfully.

Count of rows with category = 25 is only about 250, but with categories in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 25) is about 40000 rows. This must lead to extra memory demands, but mysql doesnt throw error. Why?

Any explanation to this paradox? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE1**

`EXPLAIN` with failing query

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT name, name_full, price_steps FROM `lots` WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `categories` INNER JOIN `category_lot` ON `categories`.`id` = `category_lot`.`category_id` WHERE `lots`.`id` = `category_lot`.`lot_id` AND `category_id` IN(25) ) ORDER BY `created_at` DESC;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                | key                              | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories   | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 8       | const                     |    1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | category_lot | NULL       | ref    | category_lot_lot_id_foreign,category_lot_category_id_foreign | category_lot_category_id_foreign | 8       | const                     | 1099 |   100.00 | Start temporary                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lots         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 8       | torgs.category_lot.lot_id |    1 |   100.00 | End temporary                                |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

`EXPLAIN` with success query (added 4th field)

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT name, name_full, price_steps,SUBSTRING(`name_full`, 1, 200000000000) as name_full2  FROM `lots` WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `categories` INNER JOIN `category_lot` ON `categories`.`id` = `category_lot`.`category_id` WHERE `lots`.`id` = `category_lot`.`lot_id` AND `category_id` IN(25) ) ORDER BY `created_at` DESC;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                | key                              | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories   | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 8       | const                     |    1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | category_lot | NULL       | ref    | category_lot_lot_id_foreign,category_lot_category_id_foreign | category_lot_category_id_foreign | 8       | const                     | 1099 |   100.00 | Start temporary                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lots         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 8       | torgs.category_lot.lot_id |    1 |   100.00 | End temporary                                |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

`EXPLAIN` with success query (added 4th field and `category_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25)`)

```
mysql> EXPLAIN  SELECT name, name_full, price_steps, SUBSTRING(`name_full`, 1, 200000000000) as name_full2  FROM `lots` WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `categories` INNER JOIN `category_lot` ON `categories`.`id` = `category_lot`.`category_id` WHERE `lots`.`id` = `category_lot`.`lot_id` AND `category_id` IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25) ) ORDER BY `created_at` DESC;
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                | key                              | key_len | ref                 | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2>  | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                         | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL                | NULL |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | lots         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 8       | <subquery2>.lot_id  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | categories   | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 8       | NULL                |   11 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index        |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | category_lot | NULL       | ref    | category_lot_lot_id_foreign,category_lot_category_id_foreign | category_lot_category_id_foreign | 8       | torgs.categories.id | 1883 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
4 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE2**

```
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1276 | Field or reference 'torgs.lots.id' of SELECT #2 was resolved in SELECT #1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `torgs`.`lots`.`name` AS `name`,`torgs`.`lots`.`name_full` AS `name_full`,`torgs`.`lots`.`price_steps` AS `price_steps`,substr(`torgs`.`lots`.`name_full`,1,200000000000) AS `name_full2` from `torgs`.`lots` semi join (`torgs`.`categories` join `torgs`.`category_lot`) where ((`torgs`.`category_lot`.`category_id` = `torgs`.`categories`.`id`) and (`torgs`.`lots`.`id` = `<subquery2>`.`lot_id`) and (`torgs`.`categories`.`id` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25))) order by `torgs`.`lots`.`created_at` desc |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Maybe the execution plan gives a hint? (but i agree it seems to be .... strange)

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT *` in your `EXISTS` query? There's no need to return every single column when you're using none of them. Change that to `SELECT 1 FROM` instead, which will greatly reduce the amount of memory required and increase the query performance.

Comment: @KenWhite: I think that is greatly optimized by MySQL, and that it should not matter because of the `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: @KenWhite seems like this doesnt make the difference, but thanks for hint

Comment: @Luuk explain result with extra field is the same as the original one

Comment: Can you add the explain result to your question?

Comment: I didn't say it would solve this problem. If I was doing that, I would have written it as an answer. I just wanted to point out a problem with your current code that could be corrected, and help you learn something that will help you in the future.

Comment: @Luuk query updated

Comment: @Luuk: Whether the optimizer would fix things or not is irrelevant. Teaching good coding habits is always beneficial. Saying *You can write crap code because the optimizer will probably fix it" is simply bad practice. Learning to write it properly so that you don't have to depend on the optimizer to make it better helps you write cleaner and more maintainable code. And as a general rule, `SELECT *` when you're not going to use all the columns is bad practice.

Comment: @KenWhite: The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) also only have `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *....` examples. Maybe you should raise a question [@mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bug-reports.html) for this..

Comment: @966p At the end of the explain I do see the message `2 warnings`. One of the warnings is the compiled SQL statement, but I am curious about the other warning. Can you do `SHOW WARNINGS` (immediately after the `EXPLAIN...`)?

Comment: @Luuk Excuses, I have missed your comment. Result of SHOW WARNING was attached in UPDATE2 section. Thanks a lot for your replies. 
I solved the issue on 23 nov with increasing sort_buffer_size, but still didnt solve the riddle...